# POSTMAN - mock server, using variables in example response

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have set up a mock server in Postman, and a request with a very simple example JSON response:

```
{
    "client_ref": "zzzzzzzz"
}
```

This is working fine.
However I've also set up some variables, and I'm unable to create an example response that references the variables. I have tried with local environment variables, and also with global variables.

So for instance I have a variable called 'postMockINC' that I wish to use in place of "zzzzzzzz" above.

I have tried updating the JSON in my example response body to this:

```
{
    "client_ref": "{{postMockINC}}"
}
```

and also to this:

```
{
    "client_ref": {{postMockINC}}
}
```

but in both cases the literal values are returned.
Is it possible to reference variables in example JSON responses?

Jamie